# Gather a List of Configured IP Addresses

Tags: ansible, centos7, junos-automation

I want to pull out the lines of a Juniper config that assign an IPv6 address to an interface and save that output to a file.

The output I am after is generated with the command 'show configuration | display set| match "inet6 address" '

I'm building an Ansible playbook and have pinballed off of errors to end up with the below task. It is basically giving me the complete interface configs, and I just want to narrow it down to the lines that would fit the "match" line in the manual command. The commented out filters aren't working and I can't find documentation that explains filters in a way that I understand.

```
- name: "Get selected configuration hierarchies"
  juniper_junos_config:
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    retrieve: "committed"
    config_mode : "private"
    filter: "<configuration><interfaces/></configuration>"
    #filter: "<configuration><interfaces/><family/><inet6/><address/></configuration>"
    #filter: "inet6/address"
    format: "set"
    options:
      inherit: "inherit"
    dest: "{{ inventory_hostname }}-inet6-config"
  register: response
- name: "Print result"
  debug:
    var: response
```

Output:

```
ok: [LAB-QFX5110-1] => {
    "response": {
        "changed": false,
"config": "\nset interfaces xe-0/0/0 apply-groups-except jumbo-frames\nset interfaces xe-0/0/0 description \"Test Laptop - DMZ;000\"\nset interfaces xe-0/0/0 gigether-options 802.3ad ae12\n<SNIP>\nset interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet address 100.126.0.x/32\nset interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet6 address ABCD:EF00:0000:01c4::1/128\n<SNIP>/n",
"config_lines": [
            "",
            "set interfaces xe-0/0/0 apply-groups-except jumbo-frames",
            "set interfaces xe-0/0/0 description \"Test Laptop - DMZ;000\"",
            "set interfaces xe-0/0/0 gigether-options 802.3ad ae12",
            "<SNIP>",
            "set interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet address 100.126.0.x/32",
            "set interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet6 address ABCD:EF00:0000:01c4::1/128",
            "<SNIP>",
        ],
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "Configuration has been: opened, retrieved, closed."
    }
}
```

I just want the lines that read:

***set interfaces  unit X family inet6 address XXXX:YYYY:ZZZZ:1234::1/127***

But I can't seem to plug in the correct filter.

I will also mention that if there is a better way to gather this, I am open to exploring it. It just seems like this is the task Ansible was created to perform.

Comment: not familiar with Juniper ansible module, but do you think you could show us the `response` variable structure and contents? it would help provide (hopefully) an answer to your problem. assuming your task is the optimal one, my goal would be to try parse the `response` variable, and catch the lines containing the `inet6` string.

Comment: i presume the output of the variable is loooooooong. in this case, then just its structure - so we can see the fields it contains - would suffice.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide the requested output. If I am reading your comments correctly, you are saying I have to now program Ansible to process the output?

Comment: yes, please see answer on how you can parse the `response` and get the lines you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how to do it. since your `response` dictionary contains the output split by lines, we will use the `config_lines` key, process line by line:

code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    response:
      changed: false
      config: |2-

        set interfaces xe-0/0/0 apply-groups-except jumbo-frames
        set interfaces xe-0/0/0 description "Test Laptop - DMZ;000"
        set interfaces xe-0/0/0 gigether-options 802.3ad ae12
        <SNIP>
        set interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet address 100.126.0.x/32
        set interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet6 address ABCD:EF00:0000:01c4::1/128
        <SNIP>/n
      config_lines:
      - ''
      - set interfaces xe-0/0/0 apply-groups-except jumbo-frames
      - set interfaces xe-0/0/0 description "Test Laptop - DMZ;000"
      - set interfaces xe-0/0/0 gigether-options 802.3ad ae12
      - "<SNIP>"
      - set interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet address 100.126.0.x/32
      - set interfaces lo0 unit 10 family inet6 address ABCD:EF00:0000:01c4::1/128
      - "<SNIP>"
      failed: false
      msg: 'Configuration has been: opened, retrieved, closed.'

  tasks:

  - name: find entries containing inet6 address, add to results
    set_fact:
      interfaces: "{{ interfaces | default([]) + [item] }}"
    when: item is search('inet6 address')
    with_items:
    - "{{ response.config_lines }}"

  - debug:
      var: interfaces

  - name: save results to file
    template:
      src: results.j2
      dest: /tmp/results.out
```

you will need a jinja2 template for the last task to work (under same dir as your playbook), with contents:

**results.j2:**

```
# processing results:

{% for interface in interfaces -%}
{{ interface }}
{%- endfor %}
```

1st task parses each line and if the `when` condition is met, its adding the given line to a results , the `interfaces` list. 2nd task prints that variable. 3rd task saves the results to a file under /tmp/.

hope it helps

Comment: This is SO close to what I was looking for. I am hoping to save the "interfaces" output into a file. When I add the "dest: " line to the task, it seems to invalidate the whole task. I figure I've got the syntax wrong, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: have a look at [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html?highlight=template). plz see updated answer

Comment: After I took out the minus sign in the template, I got exactly the output I was looking for. Thanks!